# Can't compile project after importing stored procedure

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

After importing a stored procedure into my datamodel the project stopped compiling.

It keeps giving me error:

```
The best overloaded method match for 
'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<TicketDataModel.sp_get_orphanjobgrades1_Result>
(string, params System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter[])' 
has some invalid arguments  C:\Users\nikolaev\Documents\MySoft\TicketManager-06 11 2013\TicketManager\TicketDataModel\TicketDataModel\TicketEntities.Context.cs 105 20  TicketDataModel
```

and

```
`Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter' to 
'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter'   
 C:\Users\nikolaev\Documents\MySoft\TicketManager-06 11 2013\TicketManager\TicketDataModel\TicketDataModel\TicketEntities.Context.cs    79  143 TicketDataModel`
```

The code in `context.cs` is as follows:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<sp_get_orphanjobgrades1_Result> sp_get_orphanjobgrades1(Nullable<System.DateTime> start_date, Nullable<System.DateTime> end_date)
{
            var start_dateParameter = start_date.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("start_date", start_date) :
                new ObjectParameter("start_date", typeof(System.DateTime));

            var end_dateParameter = end_date.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("end_date", end_date) :
                new ObjectParameter("end_date", typeof(System.DateTime));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<sp_get_orphanjobgrades1_Result>("sp_get_orphanjobgrades1", start_dateParameter, end_dateParameter);
}
```

I read that this may be because of EF 6 and that one needs to download VS 2012 Update 1 and/or EF 6 Tools for VS 2012. I downloaded the tools and I already have update 4 installed, but that doesn't help.

Why is this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The problem is that your model don't know anything about new parameters. I guess that it happens when your model using **EntityFramework (EF)** lower version (5.0 for example), but in code you are trying to use EF 6.0.

So, you should either downgrade your code to EF 5.0, or upgrade your model to 6.0.

**Upgrading model:**

1. Open Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console;
2. Choose project, that contains your model as Default project on the
   top of Console.
3. Type **"Uninstall-Package EntityFramework"** and press Enter;
4. After removing, type **"Install-Package EntityFramework -version
   6.0.0"** and press Enter again;
5. Go to **YourModelName.Context.cs** and **YourModelName.Context.tt** and replace *"using
   System.Data.Objects; using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;"* with *"using
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;"*. Also, you may need to make the
   same in all files, where this problem appears.

Or you can downgrade EF version, used in your code. For this, you should do all the same in first 3 steps but in the fourth replace **"-version 6.0.0"** with **"-version 5.0.0"**. The 5th step is not needed for this.

Comment: +1 Cool...I was running a 2012 solution on 2013....simple enough to uninstall 6.0.0. and install 4.0.0.0 which the solution was built on...worked after that

Comment: This solved my issue thanks, but every time I update my model from my database the "using..." reverts back and I have to re-type it.  Why is this happening and is there a way to stop it??

Comment: It worked for me but in my case there is no need to replace the usings in the YourModelName.Context.tt (only in YourModelName.Context.cs). It built ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To fix this issue:

If version conflicts, install package for respective version of `EF`.

If version is same, change the above namespace to `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects`

Comment: It worked for me, Thank you !
I just changed namespace "System.Data.Objects" to "System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects" and it worked ! without any upgrades (I have Entity Framework 6.1.0 installed).

Answer (score 2):

You can download new verions in msdn.

1. Download Tools for Entity Framework 6.1.0 or new versions
   in    http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762
2. Use in Package Manager Console 
   Install-Package EntityFramework -version 6.1.0 and enter
3. Restart your visual studio.
   4.Check your package Manager  and finish.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add that this happened to me after starting a brand new project. The issue was that I had created a new project, and then proceeded to update the Entity Framework, ASP.Net MVC, and other packages through the NuGet Package Manager. So, the code generated for my project no longer matched what I had installed.

The quickest solution for me was to just create a new project since I hadn't done any real work yet. I hope this helps somebody else out there.

Answer (score 1):

My situation was a new project, and I went to nuget with Install-Package EntityFramework which installed the 6.0 version, however apparently my project was already set up with an earlier version?  Not sure how, maybe the default of MVC 4.0 project...

So I had to do an Uninstall-Package -force EntityFramework followed by 
Install-Package EntityFramework -version 5.0.0

Everything worked after that.

Comment: similar situation.  Only difference is that I had to uninstall 6.0.0 and install 4.0.0.  Your situation prompted me to install an earlier version.